# How to insert images with TeXShop for Mac OS X?

Tags: graphics, texshop

I'm using TeXShop on a Mac OS X 10, I have a jpg picture (named "tt") on the desktop and I'm trying to insert it in my document; this is what I have written but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Machintosh_HD/Utenti/admin/Scrivania} }
..
\begin{document}
..
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{tt}
\end{figure}
..
\end{document}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A comment such as `it doesn't work` is not all that specific. *What* is it that does not work? Are you getting error messages? If so, what to they say?

Comment: Best to move the picture in the samedirectory as the tex file is.

Comment: You can drag and drop the .jpg to the location you wish in your document and TeXShop will create the correct includegraphics command with the correct path.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X displays “Scrivania” when the user has chosen Italian as the interface language, but the directory is still named “Desktop”. The same happens, for instance, with “Users” that's displayed “Utenti” (in Italian, with the localized name in other languages).

More importantly, you shouldn't use the disk name at the start. Simple solution:

```
\graphicspath{ {\string~/Desktop/} }
```

where `\string~` produces the correct path for your home, so you don't need to specify `/Users/admin`.

By the way, I don't think that the Desktop is the best place where you can save your image files.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop the .jpg to the location you wish in your document and TeXShop will create the correct \includegraphics command with the correct path. If you want to define the path for the \graphicspath command you can then copy what you need from that \includegraphics command.